# How do I proceed from here for this reduction formual?

Tags: integration

If $\displaystyle I_n=\int(\sin x+\cos x)^ndx$ then prove that

$nI_n=(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x+\cos x)+2(n-1)I_{n}$

My attempt:

$\displaystyle  I_n=\int(\sin x+\cos x)^ndx=\int(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x+\cos x)dx$

Integrating by parts, this is what I got:

$\displaystyle  I_n=(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x-\cos x)+(n-1)\int(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}(\sin x-\cos x)^2dx$

How should I proceed from here to get the answer? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your last integral is equal to $I_n$

Comment: It was a typo. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HInt:

$$I_n=\int(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x+\cos x)\ dx$$

$$=(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1}\int(\sin x+\cos x)\ dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d((\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1})}{dx}\int(\sin x+\cos x)\ dx\right)dx$$

$$=(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x-\cos x)-(n-1)\int(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}(\cos x-\sin x)(\sin x-\cos x)\ dx$$

Now use $(\cos x-\sin x)(\sin x-\cos x)=-(\cos x-\sin x)^2$

and $(\cos x-\sin x)^2+(\cos x+\sin x)^2=\cdots=2$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you so much!!